# How to find caret position in an NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I've an NSTextView with with several semi-colon separated strings. I need to find on which of those strings the caret has been placed. How could I do that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
NSInteger insertionPoint = [[[myTextView selectedRanges] objectAtIndex:0] rangeValue].location;
```

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 4

```
let insertionPointIndex = myTextView.selectedRanges.first?.rangeValue.location
```