# Insert text at cursor position on button press in Swift

Tags: macos, swift

My last program is written about 20 years ago, therefore my programming skills are moderate or bellow. Now I decided to try Swift and have questions.

I have search field where I would like to allow a user to enter a text using buttons.

**The problem**: I could not find the way to insert the letter/symbol to the search field at the cursor position.

lets say:

```
let buttonLetter_a = "a"
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: NSSearchField!
@IBAction func buttonLetter_a(sender: NSButton) {
    // this adds the letter a at the end of the string
    myTextField.stringValue += buttonLetter_a
}
```

How to force the button i.e. "buttonLetter_a" to insert the "a" to the string entered to "myTextField" at the cursor position?

**Please note that I need Swift help for OS X.**

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1701680/1403732 to get cursor position for starting point. Then I guess you will be able to concatenate three strings

Comment: Thank you sage444. However,  to understand convert the code you are pointing to, to Swift - I have to know Objective-C and I do not... Any Objective-C → Swift interpreter?

Comment: Munas, I know this is a year and a half later, but I would recommend using http://objectivec2swift.com