# NSTextField get cart position

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a `NSTextField` with key notification. And when key pressed I want to check if caret position is on position 0: do something, else do default action.

```
class ConsoleTextField: NSTextField {
    var commandHistory:[String] = []
    var commandPosition:Int = 0
    var keyDownMonitor:Any? = nil

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        if keyDownMonitor == nil {
            keyDownMonitor = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
                self.keyDown(with: $0)
                return $0
            }
        }
        return super.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func textDidEndEditing(_ notification: Notification) {
        super.textDidEndEditing(notification)
        if let keyDownMonitor = keyDownMonitor {
            NSEvent.removeMonitor(keyDownMonitor)
        }

        keyDownMonitor = nil
    }

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
            switch event.keyCode {
            case 125: // down arrow key
                // here I want to check current caret position in text field
            default:
                break
            }
        }
}
```

I see related questions, like this:

[How to find caret position in an NSTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701129/how-to-find-caret-position-in-an-nstextview)

But I can't make them work on Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure it out:

```
self.currentEditor()?.selectedRange.location
```